# How the "top 2% this week" was calculated?

Tags: support

I've got "top 2% this week" on the Raspberry Pi community. I've read some posts about what does top x% this week means and I don't find the answer to this question.

In addition, on Raspberry Pi User Reputation League, my account is the first one this week.

How this 2% was calculated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How this 2% was calculated?

The reputation points you accrued during that time period.

Comment: Thank you for your attention and your response. Now I got that the less the number, the better the rank.